# Resetting USB device without disconnecting it

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I use a USB cellular modem to connect to the internet. Unfortunately,  the modem sometimes connects to a low strength network and the only way to reset the connection is to unplug the modem and reconnect it. This is a nuisance and stresses the connector.

Is there a way to reset a USB device in Windows XP without physically disconnecting it?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is either go into Dev Manager and Disable and then Re-enable the device in order for your computer to no longer detect the USB and then re-discover it.

In addition, you can use the "devcon disable *hardware ID*" and then "devcon enable *hardware ID*" in order to force this action. You will just have to get the Hardware ID via your Device Management

Your other option is to download a 3rd-party application that can do this for you as well, such as "DevEject" or "Zentimo"

-Mike

Answer (score 1):

To change network go to the network connections folder and choose a better network. No need to unplug usb modems.